# Изменение стандартного цвета MenuItem и выпадающего меню Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Добрый день всем. Создаю приложение на *Windows Forms*, задний фон у него черного цвета. Текст `MenuStrip` белый. Когда щелкаю по менюшке мышью, из-за белого цвета текста надпись практически не видно.
Я создал класс, где переопределил свойства цвета:

```
public class MenuStripRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public MenuStripRenderer() : base(new Cols()) { }
}

public class Cols : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        // when the menu is selected
        get { return Color.Blue; }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.Black; }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.Orange; }
    }

}
```

В форме работаю с событиями:

```
private void fileMenu_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fileMenu.BackColor = Mr.ColorTable.MenuItemSelected;
}

private void fileMenu_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fileMenu.BackColor = Mr.ColorTable.MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin;
}

private void fileMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fileMenu.BackColor = Mr.ColorTable.MenuItemSelected;
}
```

Это не устранило мою проблему и я начал работать по событиям:

```
private void windowToolStripMenuItem_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    windowToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}

private void windowToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    windowToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

Но вот незадача, не получается изменять цвета верхней строки меню и не получается правильно настроить изменение цвета текста в выпадающем меню.

[image: Меню Файл]

[image: Открывшееся меню]

Comment: Выпадающее меню так же черного цвета с белым шрифтом должно быть?

Comment: Я пытался его сделать черным, но то же не вышло. Верхняя строка ("Файл") была серая.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно без событий:

```
public class Cols : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        // 51, 153, 255 - устанавливаем голубой цвет выбранного элемента
        // (или задаете свой)
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }

    public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
    {
        get { return Color.Black; }
    }

    public override Color ImageMarginGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.Black; }
    }

    public override Color ImageMarginGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.Black; }
    }

    public override Color ImageMarginGradientMiddle
    {
        get { return Color.Black; }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientMiddle
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemBorder
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }
}
```

Чтобы не задавать вручную белый цвет текста, создаем функцию `SetWhiteColor` (Возможно, есть решение лучше):

```
private void SetWhiteColor(ToolStripMenuItem item)
{
    item.ForeColor = Color.White;
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem it in item.DropDownItems)
    {
        SetWhiteColor(it);
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach(ToolStripMenuItem m in YourMenuStrip.Items)
    {
        SetWhiteColor(m);
    }
    YourMenuStrip.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new Cols());
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Все работает! К сожалению из-за низкого рейтинга не могу увеличить вашу карму.

Comment: @JDo, Пожалуйста. Вы можете отметить ответ, как правильный (галочка слева от ответа). Это поможет участникам, с похожими вопросами, и мне плюс)

Comment: Прекрасный ответ! А можете код отрефакторить, применив фичу C# 6, expression bodied properties? Так просто код будет более выразительным и не таким громоздким. Если что, могу сам отредактировать ответ.